# Converting NaN in dataframe to zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

I have dictionary and created Pandas using 
cars = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cars_dict, orient='index')
and 
sorted the index (columns in alphabetical order
cars = cars.sort_index(axis=1)
After sorting I noticed the DataFrame has NaN and I wasn't sure 
if the really np.nan values?
print(cars.isnull().any()) and all column shows false.

I have tried different method to convert those "NaN" values to zero which is what I want to do but non of them is working. 
I have tried replace and fillna methods and nothing works 
Below is sample of my dataframe..

```
            speedtest          size 
toyota       65                NaN 
honda        77                800
```

Comment: `df[np.isnan(df)]  = 0`

Comment: df=df.fillna(0) if not work try df=df.replace('NaN',0)

Comment: I just went for the df.replace('NaN', 0) that worked fine. thanks.

Answer (score 30):

Either use `replace` or `np.where` on the values if they are strings:

```
df = df.replace('NaN', 0)
```

Or,

```
df[:] = np.where(df.eq('NaN'), 0, df)
```

Or, if they're actually NaNs (which, it seems is unlikely), then use `fillna`:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Or, to handle both situations at the same time, use `apply` + `pd.to_numeric` (slightly slower but guaranteed to work in any case):

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Thanks to piRSquared for this one!

Comment: Generalized: `df.apply(to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')`

Answer (score 3):

@cs95's answer didn't work here.

Had to import numpy as np and use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with [np.Nan](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.NaN) and inplace = True

```
import numpy as np

df.replace(np.NaN, 0, inplace=True)
```

Then all the columns got 0 instead of NaN.