# how to speed up? replacing nan with 0 is killing my computer

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on big datasets 6 million recods.

read them from SQL Server

pivot them

all these taking some time but still ok.

after finishing pivot I need to fill Nan with zeros

but this line is killing the computer!

it is taking 20+ min and I dont know why is that!

am I doing it wrong or is there a faster better way to do it?

this is my like ( after pivoting data will be around 100,000 records

```
 df_features[np.isnan(df_features)] = 0
```

Comment: Maybe try this? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: How does df_features look like? This line should not take that long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting NaN in dataframe to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956789/converting-nan-in-dataframe-to-zero)

Comment: Could you check if this runs faster: `df_features.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)`